# creating links for d3 force layout from json file

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, force-layout

I'm new to d3 and javascript, so sorry if it's a stupid question. I have trouble with the d3 force layout. I'm able do populate the "nodes" with data, but I can't figure out how to write the correct function that constructs my links in the format `"links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},`

I tried to write a loop but it's not working, the target has "weight:NaN", because I'm referencing the parent and the node that has the same name as the parent, I guess:

```
d3.json('file.json',function(data){
    var nodes = data;
    var links = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data[i].parents.length; j++) {
              links.push({"source": i, "target": data[i].parents[j]})
      }
    }
```

My json file looks like this, I have to connect all objects with the corresponding parent (changing the json file is not not option):

```
[
{
"name": "name 1",
"parents": [
  {"name": "name 5"},
  {"name": "name 4"}
 ]
},
{
"name": "name 2",
"parents": [
  {"name": "name 1"},
  {"name": "name 3"}
  ]
 },...
]
```

I hope somebody can help and explain to me how to write this function correctly.
Thanks. susan

Comment: That's because your variable `nodes` expects a flat array, not a hierarchical structure. Then for example, the property `source` inside an object in the `links` array expects the index of the node in the `nodes` array, or a direct reference to that node object. Anyway, a force layout doesn't seem appropriate here, have you checked the tree layouts, with which you can easily manage hierarchical structures?

Answer (score 0):

D3 documentation is a little bit contrived, and IMHO it doesn't stress enough crucial parts of many features and functions. Nevertheless, you really need to read carefully several times and understand these two pieces:

- [documentation for force.nodes()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-nodes)
- [documentation for force.links()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-links)

Argument passed to `force.nodes()` must be an array. Then, you will see that argument passed to `force.links()` must also be an array, and each element of that array must be an object in the form
`{"source": source_index, "target": target_index}`
(as you already do in your code), where `source_index` and `target_index` are indexes of correspondent nodes in the nodes array (passed to `force.nodes()`) (and this is where your mistake is).

So if you look at your code, you will see that you don't pass correct values in links array. You need to find the way to populate links array with correct indexes from nodes array (let's say to convert "name 5" to appropriate index, I believe it would be 4, in your case, assuming nodes array names are "name 1", "name 2", name 3", etc...).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking. I was thinking that I have to write a loop that is going to all the names and parent names and compares them. If name == parents.name: give me the index of the parent. I just don't know how to do that. 

The actual names and parent names are like: 18e17f85458307def0a4a19ca9a1b445cd220e65, 3969a3506da09465ef49c8c724c72680b1f1b9d5,...
I just changed them for readability. Some nodes have 2 parents, most have 1.

Comment: One way to overcome this problem is that you write a function that will, for given node name, return its index in the nodes array. That function will simply go through nodes array from the beginning, compare current node name with the given name, count already checked nodes, and then return that count when given name and node name match. There may be better ways to do it, but I would do it this way, since it is fairly clear. Then you just call that function whenever you have node name, and need node index. This will not affect performance significantly, since it is done on initialization only.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your instructions really helped to write my function